# Web3 sending EIP-1559 Transaction Completed Successfully but got back an Error: invalid remainder

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

**Overview**

I am able to send an EIP-1559 transaction through Rinkeby Testnet with Web3, the transaction completes without any trouble and I do get my Ether in my Metamask Rinkeby Account.
The thing is that I am getting an *Error: invalid remainder* after the transaction completes and my program stops immediately.

**Code**

```
// EIP-1559 Transanction
// Loading dependencies
const fs = require( 'fs' ).promises;
const Web3 = require( 'web3' );
const HDWalletProvider = require( '@truffle/hdwallet-provider' );
const { mnemonicGenerate } = require( '@polkadot/util-crypto' );
const { FeeMarketEIP1559Transaction } = require( '@ethereumjs/tx' );
const Common = require( '@ethereumjs/common' ).default;

async function main () {  
    // Infura rinkeby's url
    const infuraRinkeby = "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/4fa53ccf01504cc69f0dcbdfdaa38acf";

    // Generating bip39 mnemonic
    // const mnemonic = mnemonicGenerate();

    // Loading previously generated mnemonic
    const mnemonic = ( JSON.parse( await fs.readFile( "./private/mnemonic.json" , "utf8" ) ) ).mnemonic;

    // Creating wallet from mnemonic and saving it as a web3 provider with infura
    const provider = new HDWalletProvider( mnemonic , infuraRinkeby );

    // Passing the web3 provider to web3
    const web3 = new Web3( provider );

    // Getting sending address and balance
    const sendingAddress = ( await web3.eth.getAccounts() )[0];
    var sendingAddressBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance( sendingAddress );

    console.log( " " );
    console.log( Array( 75 ).join( "=" ) );
    console.log( "Before Transaction" );
    console.log( "Address: " + sendingAddress );
    console.log( "Balance: " + sendingAddressBalance );

    // Setting receiving address
    const receivingAddress = "0x24620ddf8474c89C0Fc0c916acBcF4029C4eB47F";

    // Getting the private key for the sending address account
    const preKey = ( provider.wallets )[ sendingAddress.toLowerCase() ].privateKey.toString( 'hex' );
    const privateKey = Buffer.from( preKey , 'hex' );

    // Setting chain
    var chain = new Common( { chain : 'rinkeby', hardfork : 'london' } );

    // Constructing the raw transaction
    // To 'Speed Up' a transaction like Metamask just send a new transaction with the same nonce but with higher gas
    const rawTx = {
        "from"                  :   web3.utils.toHex( sendingAddress ),
        "to"                    :   web3.utils.toHex( receivingAddress ),
        "gasLimit"              :   web3.utils.toHex( 210000 ),
        "maxFeePerGas"          :   web3.utils.toHex( web3.utils.toWei( '1.5' , 'gwei' ) ),
        "maxPriorityFeePerGas"  :   web3.utils.toHex( web3.utils.toWei( '1.5' , 'gwei' ) ),
        "value"                 :   web3.utils.toHex( web3.utils.toWei( '0.1' , 'ether' ) ),
        "data"                  :   web3.utils.toHex( 'This is my example' ),
        "nonce"                 :   web3.utils.toHex( await web3.eth.getTransactionCount( sendingAddress , 'pending' ) ),
        "chainId"               :   "0x04",
        "accessList"            :   [],
        "type"                  :   "0x02"
    };

    // Creating a new transaction
    const tx = FeeMarketEIP1559Transaction.fromTxData( rawTx , { chain } );

    // Signing the transaction
    const signedTransaction = tx.sign( privateKey );
    
    // Generating transaction Hash
    const txHash = await web3.utils.sha3( '0x' + signedTransaction.serialize().toString( 'hex' ) );
    console.log( "Tx Hash: " + txHash );

    // Sending transaction
    await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction( '0x' + signedTransaction.serialize().toString( 'hex' ) )
    .on( 'error' , function( error ) {
        console.error( error )
    } );

    console.log( 'After Transaction' );
    sendingAddressBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance( sendingAddress );
    console.log( "Address: " + sendingAddress );
    console.log( "Balance: " + sendingAddressBalance );
    console.log( Array( 75 ).join( "=" ) );
    console.log( " " );
};

main();
```

**Screenshot of Error**

[image]

**Questions**

- How do I fix this error?
- I am trying to add this example in a project repository as a portfolio to showcase in a future personal website but I can't because it crashes after sending the transaction (the transaction is successful). **How can I catch the error without crashing the whole program?** (Already tried try catch and didn't solve anything).
- If there a library that is causing the error, **what other library can I use to replace the one crashing the program?**

**Transaction Link Proof of Transaction Completion**

[Rinkeby Transaction from rinkeby.etherscan.io](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xb9395662b14773b2dc620e8861b9dc040e79f57883f502219feb2f14caa0347c)

If you go to data in the transaction link and convert from Hex to String you will see the message *This is my example*.

Comment: I am having the same error when sending transaction to ropsten. I get 'invalid sender'. It works if I use web3's transaction object instead of ethereumjs

Comment: I have raised an issue here https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-monorepo/issues/1459

Comment: Bro, thank you for the link to your question. I was able to deduce a solution for my problem. I will be updating an answer with the solution so it can be left here documented for anyone that wants to learn how to send a transaction. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I've managed to find a solution to this question thanks to Rakz's comment.
Here is a working code for a EIP-1559 Transaction.

```
// Loading dependencies
const fs = require( 'fs' ).promises;
const Web3 = require( 'web3' );
const HDWalletProvider = require( '@truffle/hdwallet-provider' );
const { mnemonicGenerate } = require( '@polkadot/util-crypto' );
const { FeeMarketEIP1559Transaction } = require( '@ethereumjs/tx' );
const Common = require( '@ethereumjs/common' ).default;

async function main () {
    // Infura rinkeby's url
    const infuraRinkeby = "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/4fa53ccf01504cc69f0dcbdfdaa38acf";

    // Generating bip39 mnemonic
    // const mnemonic = mnemonicGenerate();

    // Loading from a previously generated mnemonic
    const mnemonic = ( JSON.parse( await fs.readFile( "./private/mnemonic.json" , "utf8" ) ) ).mnemonic;

    // Creating a wallet from mnemonic with 10 accounts
    const hdWallet = new HDWalletProvider( mnemonic , infuraRinkeby );

    // Getting the addresses of the 10 accounts
    const accountsGenerated = Object.keys( hdWallet.wallets );

    // Initialize the provider
    const web3 = new Web3( infuraRinkeby );
    
    // Initialize a wallet
    const wallet = web3.eth.accounts.wallet;

    // Migrating the accounts generated from HDWallet to web3
    for ( const account of accountsGenerated ) {
        const privateKey = ( hdWallet.wallets )[ account.toLowerCase() ].privateKey.toString( 'hex' );
        wallet.add( web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount( privateKey ) );
    }

    // Initializating the sending and receiving addresses
    const sendingAddress = wallet[ 0 ].address;
    const receivingAddress = "0x24620ddf8474c89C0Fc0c916acBcF4029C4eB47F";

    // Getting the private key for the sending address account
    const privateKey = Buffer.from( wallet[ 0 ].privateKey.replace( '0x' , '' ) , 'hex' );

    // Setting chain
    var chain = new Common( { chain : 'rinkeby', hardfork : 'london' } );

    // Constructing the raw transaction
    // To 'Speed Up' a transaction like Metamask just send a new transaction with the same nonce but with higher gas
    const rawTx = {
        "to"                    :   web3.utils.toHex( receivingAddress ),
        "gasLimit"              :   web3.utils.toHex( 210000 ),
        "maxFeePerGas"          :   web3.utils.toHex( web3.utils.toWei( '1.5' , 'gwei' ) ),
        "maxPriorityFeePerGas"  :   web3.utils.toHex( web3.utils.toWei( '1.5' , 'gwei' ) ),
        "value"                 :   web3.utils.toHex( web3.utils.toWei( '0.1' , 'ether' ) ),
        "data"                  :   web3.utils.toHex( 'TESTING TODAY' ),
        "nonce"                 :   web3.utils.toHex( await web3.eth.getTransactionCount( sendingAddress , 'pending' ) ),
        "chainId"               :   "0x04",
        "accessList"            :   [],
        "type"                  :   "0x02"
    };

    // Creating a new transaction
    const tx = FeeMarketEIP1559Transaction.fromTxData( rawTx , { chain } );

    // Signing the transaction
    const signedTransaction = tx.sign( privateKey );

    // Serializing the transaction
    const serializedTransaction = '0x' + signedTransaction.serialize().toString( 'hex' );

    // Getting the Sending Address Balance
    var sendingAddressBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance( sendingAddress );

    console.log( " " );
    console.log( Array( 75 ).join( "=" ) );
    console.log( "Before Transaction" );
    console.log( "Address: " + sendingAddress );
    console.log( "Balance: " + sendingAddressBalance );
    console.log( Array( 75 ).join( "=" ) );

    // Generating transaction Hash
    const txHash = await web3.utils.sha3( serializedTransaction );
    console.log( "Tx Hash: " + txHash );

    // Sending transaction
    await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction( serializedTransaction )
    .on( 'error' , function( error ) {
        console.error( error )
    } );

    console.log( Array( 75 ).join( "=" ) );
    console.log( 'After Transaction' );
    sendingAddressBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance( sendingAddress );
    console.log( "Address: " + sendingAddress );
    console.log( "Balance: " + sendingAddressBalance );
    console.log( Array( 75 ).join( "=" ) );
};

main();
```

Comment: What was the change that you did? Posting the whole code does not help others fix this.